# Sync data on external drive to iCloud

Tags: macos, icloud

I have an old iMac running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. My internal drive was filling up, so I connected a 4 TB external drive.

On my internal drive, my `Documents` folder contained about 8 GB data. I created a Documents folder on the external drive and moved the contents from **internal** Documents folder to the **external** Documents folder, clearing up some space.

However, the **internal** Documents folder was connected to iCloud. Is it possible to connect my **external** Documents folder to my iCloud account? If so, how do I do this? I know I can login to my iCloud account and create a new folder and upload files to it. Problem with that is that I have many folders in my new Documents folder, and it won't allow me to upload folders so I'm looking for a way to make the whole Documents folder attached to icloud.

Answer (score 3):

You can move the Documents folder to the external drive and create a symbolic link to Documents folder present on the external drive in your Home directory.

Follow the steps mentioned below:

1. Move the contents of the **internal** Documents directory to **external** Documents directory.
2. Rename the **internal** Documents directory. (You'll need to do it via Terminal by executing `mv ~/Documents ~/Documents-old` as Finder won't allow renaming.)
3. Open Terminal and create a symbolic link to the **external** Documents directory in your Home directory.

   `ln -s /Volumes/<EXTERNAL_DRIVE>/Documents ~/Documents`

Now verify that the iCloud sync is working all-right. The old **internal** Documents directory (which was renamed in step 2) can be safely deleted.

Comment: I did as you suggested but when I do a 'ls -lrt' then Documents folder does not show as a link.  The external documents folder shows as drwx------@.  Does the @ symbol imply link?

Comment: How do I tell if it worked?

Comment: @jmh Using the command mentioned, the symbolic link named `Documents` should get created inside `~/Documents`. Can you verify if that works?

Comment: From `ls` man page, `If the file or directory has extended attributes, the permissions field printed by the -l option is followed by a '@' character.`

Comment: Yes, that worked. So I deleted both documents folder and used -F option in the ln command to create the folder. That worked. To do so I had to turn off the option to have "Desktop and Documents Folders" synched to iCloud.  But now I can't turn iCloud synch back on!  How do I do that?

Comment: I don't know if above comment was clear. The system created another documents folder inside my documents folder. I assumed that wasn't cool so I tried to  delete both documents folders except system kept creating another documents folder. So to delete it I turned off option in system prefs for "Desktop and Documents Folders" to be connected to iCloud.  Now I can't turn it back on.